# Dismiss and popViewController not working when presentingViewController is UITabbarController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, dismissviewcontroller

My scence

**UITabbar** ( **UINavigation(page1)** -push-> **page2** -push-> **page3** -present-> **page4** )

From my feature I stay on page4 and want to dismiss it and pop to root ( page1 ) but when I get presentingViewController it return `UITabbarController` not my `UINavigationBarController`

My code now.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
    guard let topVc = self?.presentingViewController else { return }
    if let destinationVC = topVc.navigationController?.viewControllers.filter({$0 is Page1ViewController}).first {
        topVc.navigationController?.popToViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

My code working before I add UITabbar to my flow.

Can someone help me or explain me about root cause ? Thank you for help.

**Updated**
Now I found a solution about this but I think it not the good way enough.

```
self.viewController.dismiss(animated: true) {
    guard let topVc = Tools.getTopViewController(),
        let tabBarVc = topVc as? MainTabBarController,
        let nav = tabBarVc.selectedViewController as? BaseNavigationBarController else { return }
    if let destinationVC = nav.viewControllers.filter({$0 is WalletViewController}).first {
        nav.popToViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use closure block when dismissing at that time in previous screen call self.popToRootViewController else on you updated code I think no need fo filter direct use nav.popToRoot...

Comment: Thank you @RajaKishan for now, I use delegate for callback in previous screen.